# Which payment method do I need to use for PHP PayPal API?

Tags: php, paypal

I need to setup a payment method on my website that allows a certain user to pay another via two email address'. So essentially, user1 comes to a page, downloads an invoice and has the option to pay that invoice using a link which redirects to paypal with the prefilled details i.e. payeremail, receiveremail, amt, currencycode. Does anyone know which API call I need to make to do this? All I can really see in the API is for other users to pay my account which I already have setup for another function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need [PayPal IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn), after the payment goes through you will receive following information https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables

Here is PHP handler for the IPN, http://www.boolcast.com/development/joomla-custom-paypal-ipn

You can also look at other sample code example on PayPal site.